# Google Play Services and admob

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I have already use the google play services to put some ads in my game in libgdx. Now I want to use the GoogleApiClient, I cant find how to do they both? someone have an idea? I know how to do them seperately by using this tutorial: http://theinvader360.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html but I can't put them both together.

Someone have any idea? any help will be appriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i had to do was use the BaseGameUtils from the android samples : https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples

Then i updated the GameHelper class with this:  https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

and it worked make sure you also have your androidmanifest.xml setup correctly

it also looks like google updated their BaseGameUtils 2 days ago  so you might not need to change anything

Comment: Thank you for replaying!
But how can I updated the GameHelper class?